# Sending message from child to parent iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Well I am trying to do a simple task. Sending a message from parent window to iframe and from iframe to parent.

index.js (parent)

```
window.onload = function() {
  //Get Audio node
  let audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

  //Get iframe node
  let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('Parent To Child', '*');
  window.addEventListener('message', messagesHandler);
}

function messagesHandler(ev) {
  console.log(ev.data);
}
```

menu.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.parent.postMessage('Child to parent', '*');
  window.addEventListener('message', messagesHandler);
}

function messagesHandler(ev) {
  console.log(ev.data);
}
```

I am able to send messages from parent to child but not the other way around.
Any clues??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent load handler gets called after the iframe load handler. This leaves the `postMessage` sent from the child frame not handled.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links **and sub-frames have finished loading**.

You need to do the `postMessage`s at a time that you are sure the listeners are already registered. While you know that the child listener will be available before the parent load event, it still would be good practice to implement in a generic way and not depend on this order, so that you could use the same framework code, regardless if you are in parent or a child frame.

Another recommendation would be to not do things on the window load event, as it may fail to trigger in some situations. A better choice is [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script>
        window.onmessage = function(e){
            if (e.data == '001:hello') alert('Hello from iframe');
        };

        var insideIframe = function() {
            window.onload = function() {
                console.log('onLoad');
            };
            window.callPapa = function() {
                window.top.postMessage('001:hello', '*');
            };
            window.onmessage = function(e) {
                if (e.data == "hello") { 
                    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>Hello from parent</div>" 
                }
            };
        }

        var fnToStr = insideIframe.toString().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        var FnBody = fnToStr.substring(fnToStr.indexOf("{") + 1, fnToStr.lastIndexOf("}"));

        // Test
        var mediaData = '<html><body><div><button onclick="callPapa()">Click me</button></div>';
        mediaData += '<script>' + FnBody + '<\/script></body></html>';

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('marginwidth','0');
        iframe.setAttribute('marginheight','0');
        iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(mediaData);

        // PASTE THE IFRAME INSIDE WHATEVER RANDOM DIV
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```